# Skip line in echo in PHP

Tags: php, echo, line, break

i have this in php :

```
 echo '"dayCaption":"'.$colNumberOfWeek.' '.$numberOfWeek.'",';
```

But i want to complete this . I want to skip a line and add another variable `( $xxx for exemple )` in parentheses...

Thanks

Comment: unable to understand your question

Comment: Do you mean you want to put this extra output on a new line?

Comment: You are not trying to build a JSON String manually are you?

Comment: Yes i want to break a line( create new line below ) and add in parentheses new variable ( $xxx for exemple ) .

Comment: please mention your output so it will be easy to identify your problem

Comment: What exactly are you getting and what is expected. ?

Comment: echo '"dayCaption":"'.$colNumberOfWeek.' '.$numberOfWeek.'",';  this line displays this for exemple : 2016-2017 , and i wannt to display : 2016-2017 <br> ( 2016)

Comment: please update your question with output

Comment: DONT build JSON like this. Build and array and use [`json_encode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) on it

Answer (score 0):

i think u want to put in a Enter. so after your last value on line 1 put in  +"/r/n" (not sure if it has to be in quotes)

```
 echo $value1 . $value2 . "/r/n" . $value3

 echo '"dayCaption":"'.$colNumberOfWeek.' '.$numberOfWeek.' './r/n.' '.$value3.'",';
```

Comment: sure. just implant the /r/n function in your echo code

Comment: @B.Dionys do you know PHP? InPHP `+` is not concatenation operator it is `.`

Comment: eeh. i know a bit php. so just have to be echo $value1 . $value2 . "/r/n" . $value3 ?

Comment: Now i have this :

    echo '"dayCaption":"'.$xxx.' '.$xx.' <br /> ('.$yyy.')",';

This line display this : xxx xx <br /> (yyy) .

I want to change the size of the yyy , just of the yyy . How can i do this pliz ? 

Someone can help me ?

Comment: what do you mean. size? format? to yy? or what. Also if this posts original answer has been answered. then click the hook with the answer u found most usefull.

Comment: but can u define "size". should it be bigger text. or just in how much is in there. like: yy only

Comment: added answer under your post. just add styling

Answer (score 0):

You may try this

```
   echo '"dayCaption":"'.$colNumberOfWeek.' '.$numberOfWeek.'", '; 
  echo "</br> ";
  echo "(";
  echo $xxxx;
  echo ")";
```

Comment: I have an error : Unexpected token \ in JSON at position 79

Comment: try the second answer

Comment: ANother error ... SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 79 it's the '<' of the echo "</br>"

Comment: I have this :  echo '"dayCaption":"'.$colNumberOfWeek.' '.$numberOfWeek.' ('.$xxx.')",'; And i want to put the ('.$xxx.') below

Comment: DONT build JSON like this. Build and array and use `json_encode()` on it

Comment: Oh ? I never do this

Answer (score 0):

I have updated your code, please try this code:

```
echo "dayCaption: ".$colNumberOfWeek." ".$numberOfWeek."<br/>(".$xxx.")";
```

Or

```
echo "dayCaption: ".$colNumberOfWeek." ".$numberOfWeek;
echo "<br/>";
echo "(".$xxx.")";
```

Both will display the same results.

I hope, this will be helpful to you.